# Updating object in react under componentDidMount

Tags: reactjs

I able to get the right data from my API node.js server. however when i try to setstate the object to render it it keeps returning null

i tried to use spread operator before the response but it still not working

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

class Profile extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      UserData: null,
      isLoading: false,
      error: null
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ isLoading: true });
    axios
      .get(
        `http://localhost:5000/api/v1/profile/${this.props.match.params.platform}/${this.props.match.params.gamertag}`
      )
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data);
      })
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({
          UserData: response.data,
          isLoading: false
        });
      })
      .catch(error => this.setState({ error, isLoading: false }));
  }

  render() {
    const { isLoading, UserData } = this.state;
    if (isLoading) {
      return <p>Loading ...</p>;
    }
    console.log(UserData);
    return <div>{UserData}</div>;
  }
}

export default Profile;
```

when i try to log. the UserData log "null", but the "console.log(response.data)" works fine so it have to do something with the setState

Comment: You need to actually return response.data in the middle then()

Comment: Or just remove that then because you don't need it.

Comment: yea that is the reason, dont know what i was thinking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need two chain two then()'s, you can get the response and set the state after .then()

```js
componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ isLoading: true });
    axios
      .get(
        `http://localhost:5000/api/v1/profile/${this.props.match.params.platform}/${this.props.match.params.gamertag}`
      )
      .then(response => {
         this.setState({
          UserData: response.data,
          isLoading: false
        });
      })
      .catch(error => this.setState({ error, isLoading: false }));
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

when you chain data method like .then(), the following chained methods automatically receive value returned by the previous function.

```
getData
 .then(res => console.log(res))
```

console.log itself will return nothing, thus the following .then() method will receive nothing.

```
getData
 .then(res => console.log(res))
 .then(data => console.log(data))
```

So if you do this, the second console.log() will log null.

You can fix it by returning something in your console.log step:

```
  getData
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data);
    return data;
  })
  .then(data => this.setState({ data: data }));
```

And the second console.log() will log properly.